# How to resolve python path error while trying to write to a file from different sub directory

Tags: python

In my Python project, my logger script is supposed to create a log file in the logs dir, my logger class is present in src/logger.py and logs/ and src are at the same level. when the logger tries to create a log file it tries to find log/ in src/ dir and errors out

project structure

```
.
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── data
│   └── test_database.db
├── flask_app
│   ├── main.py
│   └── templates
│       └── index.html
├── logs
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── constants.py
    ├── logger.py
    ├── utils.py
```

````
log_file = f"logs/{today_date}.log"
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/ribahshaikh/projects/hht_webapp/src/logs/2024-01-25.log'```
````

Comment: `log_file = f"logs/{today_date}.log"` is a relative path. Relative paths are relative to the current working directory. So the question becomes, what is your working directory (it seems to be `/Users/ribahshaikh/projects/hht_webapp/src` from the error message) ? How do you run your code? Is there a [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) call in it that changes the working directory? You can check the current working directory with [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)

Comment: Perhaps, after `import os`, `log_file = f"{os.path.dirname(__file__)}/logs/{today_date}.log"`. Your module's path is in the `__file__` variable and you can use that to move up to the parent and then add the path you want.

Comment: os.path.dirname(__file__)} this will return the  path for current working directory, I need to save my logs in one directory above the current working directory

Answer (score 0):

Add ./ to the beginning of the route to go to parent folder. It is still a relative path

log_file = f"./logs/{today_date}.log"